# Howto send vars and receive model in same time from same controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In Spring boot who receive post model and in same time send vars to thymeleaf template?

```
@Controller
public class ProfilingController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model){

        FormModel form_model = new FormModel();
        model.addAttribute("form_model", form_model);
        model.addAttribute("demo", "abc");

        return "main_template";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String receive(@ModelAttribute ModelForm form_model){

        FormModel form_model = new FormModel();

        // How to set model to send the var to thymeleaf template?
        model.addAttribute("form_model", form_model);
        model.addAttribute("demo", "abc");

        return "main_template";
    }
}
```

If in post method receibe the model, how set the model to send vars to template?, if send two params does not works:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String receive(Model model, @ModelAttribute ModelForm form_model){
```

The model_form is empty.

The template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form-signin" action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${form_model}">
            <input th:field="*{email}" required="required" type="email" />
            <input th:field="*{password}" type="password" />
            <p th:text="${demo}"></p>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the post mapping method argument, try to add one more variable `ModelMap model`, add the desired properties to `model` object..

Comment: The model object works fine but the form_model is empty :(

Comment: can you provide basic code for `FormModel`. Do you have getters/setter?  Again, you are creating a empty object (i assume, since using default constructor `FormMode()`) right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `ModelMap` as below:

I have commented new `form_model` object creation assuming that you need to keep the received data to send back to the user.

```
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String receive(@ModelAttribute ModelForm form_model, ModelMap modelMap){

        //other code to call service layer & save the data

        //Commented new object creation for FormModel
        //FormModel form_model = new FormModel();

        modelMap.addAttribute("form_model", form_model);
        modelMap.addAttribute("demo", "abc");

        return "main_template";
    }
```